# dojo ---> django POST

Tags: ajax, django, dojo

I'm trying to send a json from the client using the method xhrPost dojo. But I'm getting a 403 errors. Any help?

```
var str_json = dojo.toJson(arr_markers);
console.log('json elements: '+str_json);
dojo.xhrPost({postData: str_json,
               headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
               //content:{'prueba': 'HOLA'},
               url:'/up_position_elements/',
               handleAs: 'text',
               load: function(response, ioArgs){alert('response');},
               error: function(errorMessage){}
});
```

And how to read the json in the django view?

Which method should I use?

Comment: Which django version are you using? Make sure you read about [`CSRF`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/csrf/) and set it up correctly.

Comment: django 1.3 how can I configure Csrf? thanks in advance

Comment: Follow the link in my comment (`CSRF`).

Comment: Felix, you should probably mention CSRF in an actual answer so that you can get credit if that was what tripped him up. :)

Comment: @user707711: You can accept and upvote question by clicking on the green checkmark and arrows next to them. This helps organize the site and also serves as a way to thank those who helped you.

Answer (score 0):

`403` means "forbidden" which means that the view wants a password, cookie, or other form of authentication. Could you show us the view that serves `/up_position_elements/` so that we can see what security-related decorators or logic it might contain?

Comment: The view is blank:                                                      def element_position_update(request):

    logger.warning('elements_position_update')

    return HttpResponse("")